# Ansible not gathering facts on tags

Tags: ansible, tags, ansible-facts

I'm habituated to use `--tags` when I'm using `ansible-playbook` to filter what tasks will be executed.
I recently switched from Ansible 2.7 to 2.9 (huge gap, eh ?).

I was surprised ansible did not gathering facts exclusively when I'm using `--tags`. And I saw multiple similar cases closed in GitHub like [this one](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/58867) or [this one](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/48314). It seems affects ansible since 2.8 version, but shown as resolved. Is anybody can confirm this behavior ? It seems happening from 2.8.

**ANSIBLE VERSION** :

```
ansible --version

ansible 2.9.9.post0
  config file = None
  configured module search path = [u'/opt/ansible/ansible/library']
  ansible python module location = /opt/ansible/ansible/lib/ansible
  executable location = /opt/ansible/ansible/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.6 (default, Nov 13 2018, 12:45:42) [GCC 4.8.4]
```

**ANSIBLE CONFIG** :

```
ansible-config dump --only-changed

DEFAULT_MODULE_PATH(env: ANSIBLE_LIBRARY) = [u'/opt/ansible/ansible/library']
```

**STEPS TO REPRODUCE** :

playbook test.yml :

```
- name: First test
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes
  roles:
    - { role: test, tags: test }
  tags: first

- name: Second test
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes
  roles:
    - { role: test, tags: test }
  tags: second
```

role : roles/test/tasks/main.yml

```
- debug:
    msg: System {{ inventory_hostname }} has uuid {{ ansible_product_uuid }}
```

### **Results** :

```
ansible-playbook test.yml --check
```

= No errors.

---

```
ansible-playbook test.yml --check --tags "test"
```

= failed: 1

> "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible_product_uuid' is undefined [...]"

And I can see on the output that facts are not gathered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it seems to be a purposed behaviour when you have tags on a play level:

> This is intended behavior. Tagging a play with tags applies those tags to the `gather_facts` step and removes the `always` tag which is applied by default. If the goal is to tag the play, you can add a `setup` task with tags in order to gather facts.

**[samdoran](https://github.com/samdoran)** commented [on 11 Jun 2019](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/57529#issuecomment-500886760)

---

**Please note** that this is, then, not linked to the usage of roles, as it can be reproduced by simply doing:

```yaml
- name: First test
  hosts: all
  tags:
    - first

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: System {{ inventory_hostname }} has uuid {{ ansible_product_uuid }}
      tags: test
```

Which yields the failing recap:

```
$ ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=debug ansible-playbook play.yml --tags "test"

PLAY [First test] *************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {}

MSG:

The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible_product_uuid' is undefined

The error appears to be in '/ansible/play.yml': line 7, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
    - debug:
      ^ here


PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

So you'll either have to remove the tag of you play level, or use the `setup` module, as prompted.

This can be done inside your role, so your role stops relying on variables that could possibly not be set.

Given the role *roles/test/tasks/main.yml*

```yaml
- setup:
- debug:
    msg: System {{ inventory_hostname }} has uuid {{ ansible_product_uuid }}
```

And the playbook:

```yaml
- name: First test
  hosts: all
  tags:
    - first

  roles:
    - role: test
      tags: 
        - test

- name: Second test
  hosts: all
  tags: 
    - second

  roles:
    - role: test
      tags: 
        - test
```

Here would be the run and recap for it:

```
$ ansible-playbook play.yml --tags "test"

PLAY [First test] *************************************************************************************************

TASK [test : setup] ***********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [test : debug] ***********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "System localhost has uuid 3fc44bc9-0000-0000-b25d-bf9e26ce0762"
}

PLAY [Second test] ************************************************************************************************

TASK [test : setup] ***********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [test : debug] ***********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "System localhost has uuid 3fc44bc9-0000-0000-b25d-bf9e26ce0762"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

All this run on:

```
ansible 2.9.9
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.3 (default, May 15 2020, 01:53:50) [GCC 9.3.0]
```

Comment: Ok, your solution works well and make sense for me now. 
However, I found very curious that the use of tags impacts the gathering of facts.
So, In my case, I have to be careful to not mix playbook & role tags, or gather facts as many times as roles I have (using setup module).
Thanks for the help

Comment: Well this is linked to the fact that a play or task without explicit tag actually still have one applied: the `always` tag. So when you explicitly tag a play, as prompted by the Ansible maintainer's comment mentioned in the answer, you overwrite this `always` tag and then have to specify the tag's play if you want the facts of the play to be gathered.